# Right Access Token for Microsoft Graph API / Office Planner Data

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I try to request all Office Planner Plans and Tasks of all users via Microsoft Graph API. This is a Console Application and should run as Azure WebJob. I'm struggling with the Access Token.
With an user Token I receive 403 (Forbidden) on https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userid}/plans.

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantName}", false);
var authTask = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", _config.ClientIdUser, new UserPasswordCredential(_config.Username, _config.Password));
uthTask.Wait();
AuthenticationResult userAuthnResult = authTask.Result;
var token = userAuthnResult.AccessToken;
```

With an app only Access Token I can't request the Graph API. I read somewhere that I have to use an app+user token but how can I request such a Token?

Answer (score -1):

You can only request an app+user token in the first place from an interactive application where the user can consent and provide their credentials in a Microsoft-owned user experience.  As part of that OAUTH flow you can then request a refresh token which you can store securely and pass to your webjob to run the later task.